# How to redirect output of a running program to /dev/null

Tags: io-redirection

I know that in order to suppress the output of a program I can redirect it to `/dev/null`, for example to hide all error and warning messages from chromium I can start the program like this

```
chromium-browser 2> /dev/null &
```

However, if I happen to forget about the error messages and type

```
chromium-browser &
```

(which is quite annoying when they appear in the middle of a command) I don't know what to do except for stopping the application and starting it again properly.

Can I somehow redirect error output without restarting the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also launch the browser with nohup and then close the terminal window with the following:

```
nohup chromium-browser &
```

This way, the browser will launch and detach from the console, that can then be closed quietly.

Comment: that is acceptable, except for the fact that I'll have to remember to type `nohup`

Comment: @phu On zsh at least you can put `setopt nohup` in your `.zshrc` and it will nohup everything you run; I'm not sure about other shells

Comment: yes, great, I like it this way!

Comment: Or you can create an alias... alias chromium = nohup chromium

Answer (score 21):

This was answered here : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-line) by [vladr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66516/vladr).
The answer is (quoting) :

- attach to the process in question using gdb, and run:
- p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 1) (for stdout redirection)
- p dup2(open("/dev/null", 0), 2) (for stderr redirection)
- detach
- quit

I tried it on the following script :

[edition after first comment :]

```
sleep 10 # so I can have the time to attach to the process
if [ "$sonorfather" == "father" ] # avoid infinite recursion 
then 
   sonorfather=son ./test & 
fi 

while true 
do 
   echo "stdout $sonorfather" 
   echo "stderr $sonorfather" >&2 
   sleep 1 
done
```

I disabled the stderr output before the son process was created, here is the output :

```
stdout father 
stdout son 
stdout father 
stdout son 
[and so on...].
```

I hope this answer your question : the son process stderr was redirected too.

Comment: that was very good, but then I may have problems with chromium, as it spawns a new process for each browser tab, anyway to resolve?

Comment: Edited my post to answer you.

Comment: Look like I'll need to redirect the output before the child processes are created?
Thanks for the knowledge, but regarding the complexity I'd just go with `nohup` :)

Comment: Technically, this leaks duplicate file descriptors for `/dev/null`, but in practice that does not significantly affect anything.

Answer (score 6):

You could also setup an alias for `chromium-browser` to instead run `chromium-browser 2> /dev/null`

e.g. if you are using bash, edit /home/username/.bashrc and add line:

```
chromium-browser='chromium-browser 2> /dev/null'
```

or better yet

```
chrome='chromium-browser 2> /dev/null'
```

and save some keystrokes.