# Can I redirect stdout from a background application after starting it?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect output of a running program to /dev/null](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/redirect-output-of-a-running-program-to-dev-null)

Is it possible to change stdout after starting something as a background application in the command line?

Say I run test.py:

```
import time

while True:
    print "Hello"
    time.sleep(1)
```

and then do:

```
$ python test.py &
```

Can I redirect the output to `/dev/null` somehow?

Relates to: [How to redirect output of a running program to /dev/null](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/redirect-output-of-a-running-program-to-dev-null)

With an answer on this site: [How to redirect output of a running program to /dev/null](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/redirect-output-of-a-running-program-to-dev-null/1543#1543) by [Mike Perdide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1432/mike-perdide)

It's also a direct duplicate of a StackOverflow question: [Redirect STDERR / STDOUT of a process AFTER it's been started, using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-line)

Comment: See the answer for this [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/redirect-output-of-a-running-program-to-dev-null/1543#1543).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you taught the program to do so somehow (say, on receipt of a particular signal such as `SIGUSR1` it reopens `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` on `/dev/null`).  Otherwise, once it's been started you have very little control over it.